# JPA LazyInitializationException when returning a JAXB Object through a Webservice

Tags: jpa, jboss, jaxb, jax-rs, jboss6.x

I'm working with JBoss. i created a simple JAX-RS Webservice that retrieves a JPA Entitiy from the database and returns it to the user. As soon as I have a relationship (@OneToOne) to another Entity I get a LazyInitializationException. The Reason is simple: The Relationship was not initialized by JPA (lazy loading) and when jaxb tries to serialize it, everything breaks.

But how do i solve this?

I could touch the relationship before i return the object. Not nice and complex for greater object networks.

I could extend my Persistence context, so my session is still active during jaxb serialization. Great idea, but how?

Is there a standart, best practice way to solve my problem.

Laures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to ensure you are annotation the properties (accessors) and not the fields (instance variables), when dealing with JPA entities.

Below is an example of creating a JAX-RS service with JAX-RS, JAXB, and JPA:

- [Part 1 - The Database](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html)
- [Part 2 - Mapping the Database to JPA Entities](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-25.html)
- [Part 3 - Mapping JPA entities to XML (using JAXB)](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html)
- [Part 4 - The RESTful Service](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html)
- [Part 5 - The Client](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html)

Comment: we switched from hibernate to eclipselink and now it works. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@XmlTransient` annotation to prevent the relationship from being serialized.

Comment: But I want to serialize the relationship. But when jaxb tries to i get an exception.

Comment: You should't serialize a lazy loading relationship. How you are suppose to use it once it's deserialized?

Comment: I don't get the problem. The relationship should of cause be loaded before its serialized so its conpletly serialized into the xml. at least thats what i want.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But in this case you have to resolve all lazy relations by yourself. Otherwise nobody can know how deeply you want to go to resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the relationship annotation to eagerly fetch the object.

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```